# How to format YAML to be more readable

Tags: php, yaml, symfony

I want to change this piece of YAML:

```
calls:
    - [ setReader, ["@sonata.admin.audit.manager", "@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"]]
    - [ setTemplates, [{show: XxxBundle:PmodOrder:show.html.twig, edit: XxxBundle:PmodOrder:edit.html.twig, create: XxxBundle:PmodOrder:create.html.twig}]]
```

How can I format it in a more readable way? I don't like it to be so long in one single line.

I've tried this;

```
calls:
    - [ setReader, ["@sonata.admin.audit.manager", "@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"]]
    setTemplates:
        - show: XxxBundle:PmodOrder:show.html.twig
        - edit: XxxBundle:PmodOrder:edit.html.twig
        - create: XxxBundle:PmodOrder:create.html.twig}]]
```

and this;

```
calls:
    - [ setReader, ["@sonata.admin.audit.manager", "@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"]]
    - setTemplates:
        - show: XxxBundle:PmodOrder:show.html.twig
        - edit: XxxBundle:PmodOrder:edit.html.twig
        - editTwo: XxxBundle:PmodOrder:create.html.twig
```

But it didn't work, I can't find something about this format: `- [ xxx, [{yyy: zzz, aaa: bbb}]]` and how to break it up in more lines.

Answer (score 1):

YAML flow style nodes can be broken into multiple lines, as long as they have at least the indentation of the surrounding block node:

```
calls:
  - [ setReader, ["@sonata.admin.audit.manager",
                  "@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"]]
  - [ setTemplates, [{
        show:   XxxBundle:PmodOrder:show.html.twig,
        edit:   XxxBundle:PmodOrder:edit.html.twig,
        create: XxxBundle:PmodOrder:create.html.twig}]
    ]
```

It is also possible to use the compact block notation which allows multiple list items starting at the same line:

```
calls:
  - - setReader
    - - "@sonata.admin.audit.manager"
      - "@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"
  - - setTemplates
    - - show:   XxxBundle:PmodOrder:show.html.twig
        edit:   XxxBundle:PmodOrder:edit.html.twig
        create: XxxBundle:PmodOrder:create.html.twig
```

Comment: Your first example is nice.  Think you may have some syntax issues with the second.  At least I could not get it to work.

Comment: @Cerad It is valid YAML according to the specification. If Symfony fails to parse it, that's a bug. The Symfony YAML implementation is not the most accurate one from all I've heard (never used it myself). For comparison, you can check [NimYAML](https://nimyaml.org/testing.html) [my work] or the [reference parser](http://ben-kiki.org/ypaste/), both of which parse it without errors.

Comment: You can push `"@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"]]` al the way to the first column, which makes your first sentence look inaccurate (Is "they" referring to the nodes or the multiple lines?.

Comment: @Cerad Note that the symfony3 parser cannot handle the YAML in these examples, although **it is** correct YAML.

Comment: @Anton - The first one works fine in Symfony.  I learned something from it.  Still a bit suspicious of the second one.  In any event, looks like another drive by question anyways.

Comment: @Anthon According to the spec, flow content *must* be indented at least to the indentation of the enclosing block node. However, since indenting it lesser is unambiguous, some implementations support it anyway. But you shouldn't depend on it.

Answer (score 0):

This works though I don't know if it is easier to read or not:

```
try2:
    class: AppBundle\Try2
    calls:
        - [ setReader, ["@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager", "@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"]]
        -
            - setTemplates
            -
                -
                    show:   XxxBundle:PmodOrder:show.html.twig
                    edit:   XxxBundle:PmodOrder:edit.html.twig
                    create: XxxBundle:PmodOrder:create.html.twig
```

If this is your own class then I would suggest creating an addTempate($name,$file) method and then just calling it three times.

Comment: Where does the `class: AppBundle\Try2` come from, it is not in @Mentos93 original post.

Comment: @Anthon Try2 is just a simple class I wrote to test the configuration.  Mentos just left it out of of his question as it's not really relevant.  All service definitions need a class.  At least until the latest dependency injection container is released.

Answer (score 0):

The answer flyx gives you a correct solution, but doesn't indicate what you have been doing wrong in your trials to find a solutions, and doesn't solve the problem because you are encountering restrictions in the PHP based YAML parser that symfony3 is using.

This:

```
calls:
    - [ setReader, ["@sonata.admin.audit.manager", "@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"]]
    setTemplates:
        - show: XxxBundle:PmodOrder:show.html.twig
        - edit: XxxBundle:PmodOrder:edit.html.twig
        - create: XxxBundle:PmodOrder:create.html.twig}]]
```

has problems. You start out with the value for the mapping key `calls` to be a sequence by having a dash (`-`) before the (flow style) sequence element that starts with `[ setReader, ["@sonat...`. Then at the same indentation level you have a mapping key `setTemplates` and that is not allowed in YAML. The trailing `}]]` also should be removed as they are not part of the mapping value `XxxBundle:PmodOrder:create.html.twig}]]`

You fixed the syntax error in your second example by inserting the extra dash (and removed the trailing `}]]`), but did not notice that you actually removed a full node by making the mapping

```
setTemplates, [{show: XxxBundle:PmodOrder:show.html.twig, edit: XxxBundle:PmodOrder:edit.html.twig, create: XxxBundle:PmodOrder:create.html.twig}]]
```

an element of the sequence that is the value for `calls` instead of an element of a sequence of a sequence that is value for `calls`.

---

This problem comes from trying to rewrite too many things at the same time and/or by starting at the wrong end.

> *In YAML, if you want to rewrite flow style nodes to block style, you should start at the top level and work inwards, so you can do so one step at a time.*

This is, because flow style can occur within itself and within block style, but block style cannot occur within flow style, only within other block style.

Therefore your first step in rewriting should be to take the outermost sequence that is in flow style and rewrite it (I am using 2 space indent as that seems more appropriate if line length is a concern):

```
calls:
  - [ setReader, ["@sonata.admin.audit.manager", "@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"]]
  - 
    - setTemplates
    - [{show: XxxBundle:PmodOrder:show.html.twig, edit: XxxBundle:PmodOrder:edit.html.twig, create: XxxBundle:PmodOrder:create.html.twig}]
```

You can, but don't have to, have the first element of a block style sequence within a block style sequence on the same line as the parent, **but the YAML parser symfony3 uses doesn't allow this**. The general procedure is:

1. replace the outermost `[` with a `-`
2. replace any `,` **that is not within a nested node (between `[]` or `{}` that are not part of a scalar string), with a `-` that is on a newline with the same indentation as the `-` in step 1.
3. remove the final `]`

If you are using PHP, also move the first `-` to a new line, because of a restriction of the PHP parser.

This doesn't reduce the line length much, so repeat the above steps on the next level which is a sequence with only one element:

```
calls:
  - [ setReader, ["@sonata.admin.audit.manager", "@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"]]
  - 
    - setTemplates
    - 
      - {show: XxxBundle:PmodOrder:show.html.twig, edit: XxxBundle:PmodOrder:edit.html.twig, create: XxxBundle:PmodOrder:create.html.twig}
```

Now attack the next level which is a mapping. The steps for that are:

1. remove the outermost `{`
2. replace any `,` **that is not within a nested node (between `[]` or `{}` that are not part of a scalar string), and align the key (the part before `:`  on a newline with the same indentation as the key in step 1.
3. remove the final `}`
4. If any of the key-value pairs are both quoted and are separated by just a colon (`:`) instead of colon with space, insert a space after the colon and optionally remove quotes when possible.

This last step doesn't affect your code, but might be necessary for more JSON like YAML.

Doing these steps gets you:

```
calls:
  - [ setReader, ["@sonata.admin.audit.manager", "@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"]]
  - 
    - setTemplates
    - 
      - show: XxxBundle:PmodOrder:show.html.twig
        edit: XxxBundle:PmodOrder:edit.html.twig
        create: XxxBundle:PmodOrder:create.html.twig
```

The YAML gives the same loaded results at every step. Apply the same steps on the `[ setReader...` part and you are done:

```
calls:
  - 
    - setReader
    - 
      - "@sonata.admin.audit.manager"
      - "@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"
  - 
    - setTemplates
    - 
      - show: XxxBundle:PmodOrder:show.html.twig
        edit: XxxBundle:PmodOrder:edit.html.twig
        create: XxxBundle:PmodOrder:create.html.twig
```

If you cannot check each step with symfony3, you can check every step with a [PHP based YAML checker/converter](http://codebeautify.org/yaml-to-json-xml-csv). It is not the best parser out there, but at least it has the same restrictions as the one symfony3 uses.